# How to ssh to a docker container on ec2 ubuntu host from outside machine

Tags: docker, ssh, amazon-ecs

I am having docker Demon running on a ubuntu ec2 host.

I am able to setup an sshd conatainer on this ubuntu ec2 host and able to ssh in from the docker host .i.e.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-16-27-205:~/docker-work$ sudo docker run -d -P --name ssh-enabled ssh-enabled
bb7f535124b3df403ae97da770fe2e4a4969a7ecddfb5d546aaddfe00e40374d

ubuntu@ip-172-16-27-205:~/docker-work$ sudo docker port ssh-enabled
22/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32768

ubuntu@ip-172-16-27-205:~/docker-work$ ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 32768

The authenticity of host '[127.0.0.1]:32768 ([127.0.0.1]:32768)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is e6:74:aa:52:8e:3d:19:7a:92:da:85:d4:b9:f9:ed:f1.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:32768' (ECDSA) to the list of known      hosts.
root@127.0.0.1's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-30-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

 The programs included with the Ubuntu system are free software;
 the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
 individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Ubuntu comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by
applicable law.

root@bb7f535124b3:~#
```

However I am not sure how could I connect to this container from outside docker host.

I can ssh to docker host from an outside machine like below

```
 ssh -i /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx.pem ubuntu@172.16.27.205
```

however I wish to ssh directly to container

docker container is up as shown with below command response

```
ubuntu@ip-172-16-27-205:~/docker-work$ sudo docker ps -as

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS                      PORTS                   NAMES               SIZE
bb7f535124b3        ssh-enabled         "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      8 minutes ago       Up 8 minutes                0.0.0.0:32768->22/tcp   ssh-enabled         32.51 kB (virtual 868.4 MB)
```

as the docker host is listening on port 32768 When I try to ssh container with  user root it fails

```
rbharadwaj@syd01-devops-ansible02:~$ ssh -i '/home/xxxxx/xxxxxxx.pem' root@172.16.27.205 -p 32768 -v
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1  Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat  0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ED25519   3e:6a:c6:9e:34:98:2e:81:b5:e1:88:d1:15:63:bb:41
debug1: checking without port identifier
 The authenticity of host '[172.16.27.205]:32768 ([172.16.27.205]:32768)' can't be established.
 ED25519 key fingerprint is 3e:6a:c6:9e:34:98:2e:81:b5:e1:88:d1:15:63:bb:41.
 Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
 Warning: Permanently added '[172.16.27.205]:32768' (ED25519) to the list of   known hosts.
 debug1: ssh_ed25519_verify: signature correct
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
 debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
 debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Trying private key: /home/rbharadwaj/syd01-devops-ruc-app-instances
 debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
 debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
 debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
 Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Thinking the private key is of user Ubuntu I also tried to ssh into container like below however it fails

```
ssh -i '/home/xxxx/xxxxx.pem' ubuntu@172.16.27.205 -p 32768
```

kindly suggest how can I can connect to container directly in above scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from ssh looks like you have not correctly set up the private key. Is it in the correct location within the container (/root/.ssh/authorized_keys) and does it have the right permissions?

```
chmod 700 /root/.ssh
chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: Could you, please help me to highlight what exactly in the logs pointed this is the issue of authorised keys.

Comment: Just those two lines:

 debug1: Trying private key: /home/rbharadwaj/syd01-devops-ruc-app-instances
 debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker

I have encountered this problem before and is was related to file permissions.

Answer (score 2):

It is not always advised to set up your container to run ssh. If you need to monitor logs, control services etc. then you may be better of finding other ways of accomplishing this (log aggregators, etc.) instead of setting direct ssh access to your container.

See https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/ for more info.

I understand that this doesn't answer your question directly. However, it's unclear why you need direct access to your container other than convenience. How are you managing ssh keys?

Comment: I have an existing setup, which uses ansible for deployment (ansible ssh on remote host for configuration management), I am trying to setup containers and use my ans-bile host to direclty connect with conntainers and do deployments.

I understand that I can have ansible on docker host itself, however to make as minimal change as possible to current deployment configuration-management strategy. I am look achieve above scenario

Comment: It just seems like getting Jenkins to build your updated container and push it out to your hosts is the standard way of doing things in a reproducible way rather than using playbooks. FWIW this is why there are DevOps frameworks like Jenkins and ECS to facilitate blue-green deployment of your revisions. IMO it seems cleaner to capture your revisions in your docker file than rely on an out-of-date Dockerfile that needs to be updated by an Ansible playbook. Anyways! I am glad you found a solution. Cheers @RuchirBharadwaj!

Answer (score 1):

There was no /root/.ssh folder in container I did following as recommneded above.

1.) Created a /root/.ssh directory in container

2.) Created a authorised files

3.) place the content of public key from the host I am trying to connect to this host

and I was able to connect